# Two's Complement algorithm in Python

Tags: python

I have to do a two's complement conversion of a 3D surface, each element representing a 12 bit two's complement number.

In order to convert the array I have the following code:

```
for x in np.nditer(array, op_flags=['readwrite']):
    x[...] = twos_comp(x, 12)
```

where I found the following function online:

```
def twos_comp(val, bits):
"""compute the 2's complement of int value val"""
if (val & (1 << (bits - 1))) != 0: # if sign bit is set e.g., 8bit: 128-255
    val = val - (1 << bits)        # compute negative value
return val
```

However, the result I'm getting doesn't make any sense. Is my code wrong?

The other thing I have tried is:

```
        for x in np.nditer(array, op_flags=['readwrite']):
            if x > 2047:
                x[...] = (2047 - x)
            else:
                x[...] = x
```

but again the data doesn't look "right". Any suggestions?

Thanks

By "not right" I mean that I'm expecting a surface that looks like
[image: expected surface]

But, instead I'm getting a surface that looks like this [image: resultant surface] (there is also a multiplier of 80 that explains why the numbers in the z-axis are so large)

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't make any sense" and "doesn't look right". Could you share some sample and show what is returned vs. what **should** be returned? In short a [mcve] would help a lot :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this simple function

```
def twos_comp(val):
    return 0b111111111111 - val       # 12 ones
```

You may test it with

```
val = 0b111100001111
print("{:012b}".format(twos_comp(val)))
```

and you will got

> 000011110000

If it is not what you wanted, use this function instead

```
def twos_comp(val):
    return 0b1000000000000 - val      # 1 with 12 zeroes
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this has got it. Any idea why I'm getting a negative of what I expect?

Answer (score 0):

Some relative contents are already available here:

[Python - Most effective way to implement two's complement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813262/python-most-effective-way-to-implement-twos-complement)

and here:

[Two's Complement in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604464/twos-complement-in-python)

Comment: Thanks, I've read most of them and that's where I've got my existing code from. Does `np.nditer(array, op_flags=['readwrite'])` do what I think it does? That is loop through every element of the array, updating the value by the result of the code in the loop